# How to pass data through mapped promises?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, nested, es6-promise

I have a three stage mashup script that checks newest rentals from the local video shop and then gets their critics percentages and concensus from Rotten Tomatoes (RT):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function (){
        getNewRentals(url).then(function(ids){
            var mapped = ids.map(function(id, f){
                return function(){
                    return getRentalSpecs(id, f).then(function (f, name, year){
                        return getRotten(f, name, year); // Gets only f!
                    });
                }
            });
            var m = mapped[0]();
            for(var i = 1; i < mapped.length; i++) {
                m = m.then(mapped[i]);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

All is well, except that only *f* is passed to the last function getRotten, but **not** *film* name nor *year*. There must be something wrong with the mapping loop, because all three functions use indentical jquery getJSON's (via Yahoo YQL) identically wrapped inside standard js promises that identically resolve to params mentioned in the code. So if the data is passed from the 1st function to the 2nd, why not from the 2nd to the 3rd as well?

I've been roasting in this callback/promise hell for a few weeks now and am pretty blistered by now. This is also my first post to *SO*, so please bear with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A promise represents a single value, which is passed as one argument to any `then` handler. Use an object or array where you need to pass multiple values (whichever is more appropriate):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button').click(loadRotten);
});

function loadRotten () {
    return getNewRentals(url)
        .then(function (ids) {
            return Promise.all(ids.map(getRentalSpecs));
        })
        .then(function (objects) {
            return Promise.all(objects.map(function (obj) {
                return GetRotten(obj.f, obj.name, obj.year);
            });
            // Or refactor `GetRotten` to accept a single object
            // return Promise.all(objects.map(GetRotten));
        });
    });
}

// Or, using ES6, assuming refactor of `GetRotten`:

function loadRotten () {
    return getNewRentals(url)
        .then(ids => Promise.all(ids.map(getRentalSpecs)))
        .then(objects => Promise.all(objects.map(GetRotten));
}
```

You will have to amend `getRentalSpecs` so that it resolves with an object with the properties `f`, `name`, and `year`.

I have refactored your code to use `Promise.all()`, which makes it easier to understand. It did not seem necessary to map to function expressions and call each of these in sequence manually, as they do not depend on each other.

Comment: Thank you very much @sdgluck! In addition to above I just changed getRentalSpecs to _resolve( { f, name, year } )_ and it works like a charm now! Even though object resolve looks familiar, I've never seen it in words that promise represents only a single value.Your answer was so swift that I quite didn't manage to edit the copy/paste mistakes of my code. Hence the differences in the for loop.

Comment: Oh, the comments close so fast! I meant that I changed the resolve part of the 2nd function to `resolve( { f, name, year } )`.

Comment: @spo You're welcome. :-) I added an ES6 alternative to my answer, which is even more succinct, as perhaps you are using a transpiler.

Comment: Thank you again, @sdgluck. Arrow function is new to me and looks so baffling at first glance that I need to study it first. I'm not using transpiler, so the likely inconsistensies in my code come from the ever-changing landscape of the promised land: I've just jumped the bandwagon and it has been pretty hard for me to form a coherent image of promises. Differences between jquery and vanilla js have not helped any either.